# How to call shell functions as a child process?

Tags: shell, rust, nvm

I have a `nvm` installed by homebrew (`brew install nvm`). And I want to call it inside a CLI that I'm writing in Rust, to install and switch node.js versions inside my Rust program.

The problem is: `nvm` is a shell function, not a file entrypoint. And unfortunately the child process spawned by the Rust `tokio::process::Command` only inherit the parent process's environment and `PATH`, but not the shell functions.

> Constructs a new Command for launching the program at path program, with the following default configuration:
>
> - No arguments to the program
> - Inherit the current process's environment
> - Inherit the current process's working directory
> - Inherit stdin/stdout/stderr for spawn or status, but create pipes for output

https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.0/tokio/process/struct.Command.html

When I tried to call `tokio::process::Command::new("nvm");` I got:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'Command not fail: Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" }'

Nothing changes if I run with sudo, because I suppose that `nvm` doesn't exist to my child process.

How can I access `nvm`, or more simply, shell functions inside my Rust program?

Comment: If you explained what you're trying to accomplish, it would allow a better answer. If you're trying to change which node interpreter the shell that starts your Rust program uses, that's very different from the case where your Rust program needs to start a node program as a subprocess and is trying to select an interpreter for that subprocess alone.

Comment: I edit the question with my major purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answering The Literal Question

It's very unlikely to be meaningfully useful to you, but you can export shell functions through the environment if your shell is bash or has similar extensions.

Given the following Rust program named `example.rs`:

```rust
use std::process::Command;
use std::process::Stdio;
fn main() {
  Command::new("bash")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg("myfunction")
    .stdout(Stdio::inherit())
    .status();
}
```

...the following shell program:

```sh
myfunction() { echo "This is a function call"; }
export -f myfunction
rustc example.rs && ./example
```

...will emit as output:

```
This is a function call
```

---

#### Sourcing In-Process

You can also have your bash interpreter source the file that defines your function, and not need to export it:

```rust
use std::process::Command;
use std::process::Stdio;
fn main() {
  Command::new("bash")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg(". \"$0\" && \"$@\"")
    .arg("/path/to/nvm.sh")
    .arg("nvm")
    .arg("install")
    .arg("12")
    .stdout(Stdio::inherit())
    .status();
}
```

This works for `nvm install`, which is run for side effects (downloading an interpreter) that aren't relevant to the calling shell. It **does not** do anything particularly useful in the context of `nvm use`, because the shell that it's run in immediately exits, so the state changes made are immediately thrown away.

---

### Explaining Why That Answer Is Useless

#### (for reconfiguring the user's interactive shell)

If `nvm` could be called this way, it wouldn't need to be a shell function in the first place.

The whole point of nvm being a shell function is to let it modify the state of the shell in which it's invoked (modifying the shell's variables, working directory, or other internal state). You cannot modify the state of a shell from any process except that shell itself, period, full-stop.

What you can do is have a program that writes valid shell syntax to its stdout, and have the shell in which the function is defined eval that program's output. This is a fairly common pattern in such use cases where no other option exists -- see how folks run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` for an example.

Mind, bash does let you export functions into the environment -- you can run `export -f nvm`, and then a child process that is also a copy of bash will have a `nvm` function defined -- but this is of very little value, because that new copy of bash has a separate environment; changing it won't modify the parent shell's environment, and *if the nvm command didn't need to modify the parent shell's environment, it wouldn't need to be a function in the first place.*

Comment: You taught me a lot! Thank you so much! My purpose is quite simple, check and install node.js versions using `nvm`. I'm writing a CLI to padronize developer environments (is in Rust because i want to improve my skills on it). So, seems that i don't do what i want with `nvm`.

Comment: If this "installing" in the sense of doing downloads and the like, without needing to actually activate it for the calling shell, one thing you _can_ do is something like `bash -c '. /path/to/nvm.sh && nvm "$@"' _ ...nvm... ...arguments... ...here...`, where you're sourcing the script that provides `nvm` in the same interpreter that you're invoking it from. I'm still not quite sure enough what your use case is to know if that's helpful or not.

Comment: @RonaldRodrigues, ...I edited in an example showing how `nvm install` can be usefully run from Rust.